# How to do proxy or rewrite only missing cgi-scripts of Apache server to Nodejs Express server?

Tags: node.js, apache, express, proxy

In my Apache server configuration contains the below configuration for CGI scripts

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -Indexes -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted

        RewriteBase   "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/"
        RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-f
        RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-d
        RewriteRule "(.*)" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/cgi-bin/$1" [R,L]
        #RewriteCond   "$1.cgi"          -f
        #RewriteCond   "$1.cgi"          !-f
        #RewriteRule   "(.*).cgi"                "http://127.0.0.1:8080/cgi-bin/$1.cgi"
</Directory>
```

I had set up another server to handle the missing scripts from '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/' location.

1. Existing 'script1.cgi' files server from apache server. **(don't need to proxied for -> /cgi-bin/script1.cgi)**
2. Some non-existing 'script2.cgi' files are handled with Node Express server as endpoints, that listen to port 8080 **(/cgi-bin/script2.cgi request proxied to http://127.0.0.1:8080/cgi-bin/script2.cgi).**

My configuration doesn't work for these above cases, I try both proxy and rewrite options in the Apache server.

When I am using the below proxy, only access Nodejs endpoints. It doesn't run apache CGI scripts

```
ProxyPass "/cgi-bin" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/cgi-bin"
ProxyPassReverse "/cgi-bin" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/cgi-bin"
```

How to do proxy or rewrite only missing cgi-scripts of Apache server to Nodejs Express server?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistakes in the rewrite rule

updated one:

using proxy and rewrite rules combination **[P,QSA,L]** in the below statement

It works for me.

```
RewriteEngine  on
ProxyRequests on
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyExpressEnable on

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -Indexes -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted

        RewriteBase   "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/"
        RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-f
        #RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"       !-d
        RewriteRule "(.*)" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/cgi-bin/$1" [P,QSA,L]
        #RewriteCond   "$1.cgi"          -f
        #RewriteCond   "$1.cgi"          !-f
        #RewriteRule   "(.*).cgi"                "http://127.0.0.1:8080/cgi-bin/$1.cgi"
</Directory>
```